# Invalid Xml data and Oracle error 1407, Cannot update ID to null, when not trying to update the ID

Tags: xml, oracle

I have an Oracle server running on a Linux box.  When a particular Update statement runs inside a sproc, I receive error ORA-1407 and invalid data is written into an XmlType field.  The sproc is attempting to update the Xml but is not attempting to update the ID.  So the call being made looks like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET x = foo, y = bar, my_xml = xmldata where the_field = my_field
  returning id into l_id
```

At this point Oracle returns "ORA-01407: cannot update ID to NULL", and the field my_xml now has corrupt data in it.

If I do this a few times, the Oracle process eventually dies at seemingly random places with the error "ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error".

Have you seen anything similar?  Any hints on what steps I can take to troubleshoot?

Comment: 10G 10.2.0.4 64bit CPU October 2010

Comment: There was an issue with older versions of Oracle when a before insert trigger was defined on a table with an UPDATE..RETURNING statement. Don't think that applies here.

Comment: Is there anything in the alert log file for the database?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes, there is a trigger.  It sets one field before inserting and two fields before updating.

Comment: DCookie - have further information on the older version issue?  Maybe it's something that was missed in Linux version updates.

Comment: @Ben can you add the trigger code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

May seem silly, but does the record have a non-null value in the id to begin with.

It is possible to have a constraint that is enabled but not validated so existing data may violate the constraint. Perhaps the update is pushing the constraint to be enforced.

Comment: I don't think so.  If so, the problem is a different one - why is Oracle writing null values to a primary key?  :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is if the where condition of the UPDATE return 0 tuples then id would be null.

Hard to say without any data. You can try with a small set of your data and see where it breaks.